# What is wrong with my Beamer preamble?

Tags: beamer

I have a Beamer file that starts

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{sidebartab}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}


\title{I'm disabled, I'm also abled}
\author{Peter L. Flom}
\date{\today}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}
```

I am getting errors

```
    Runaway argument?
\let \AtEndDocument \@firstofone \@enddocumenthook \@checkend {docume\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> Fall2014.tex
```

I have no idea what this means.

I tried commenting out most of the preamble, but still got errors.

Thanks

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If i add `\end{document}` the code doesn't generate error.

Comment: The `\usepackages` and `\begin{document}` are there already. My file is large, but I can add a small version.

Comment: Morever if i add a *frame* for the title `\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}` -> *no problem*

Comment: OK, apparently the problem is later in the file, even though it shows up as being at the beginning.  I will work on it.  Should I leave this question up or delete it?

Comment: With that error message, I'd guess you've forgotten an `}` somewhere :-)

Comment: One comment: there is no need to call `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer, as it already provides this functionality.

Answer (score 14):

I solved the problem.  It was a missing `\end{frame}` much later in the document.

I think that this error is sufficiently opaque that some documentation that this is one possible reason for it should be on the web somewhere, and no better place than here.

But if the moderators disagree, I will delete the post

Thanks for the help

Comment: As [this answer points out](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/230/9077), "It's actually not uncommon to end up finding the solution yourself when you start trying to construct a minimal example". It seems like you experienced that now. If anything, your experience just highlights the importance of constructing a ``minimal`` example.